# Android: Re-request permission

Tags: android, permissions, gmail

My app requires Gmail app (NOT Android version) needs to be at version 2.3.6 or higher on Froyo or Gingerbread; 4.0.5 or higher on Honeycomb and ICS.

Also, I use "com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER" permission. I believe above permission is either not granted or not available with older Gmail app versions.

My app works well if the device already has up-to-date Gmail app installed. However, if the user installs my app first and then update the Gmail app, my app will fail.

Here's the Logcat:
Launched with older Gmail app:

```
08-14 16:13:12.370 E/DatabaseUtils(22386): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gm.provider.PublicContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.gm/_____@gmail.com/labels from pid=22456, uid=10113 requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER
```

Launched after the latest gmail app installed:

```
08-14 16:14:17.105 W/PackageManager( 1974): Not granting permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_CONTENT_PROVIDER to package com.ellevsoft.gmailunread because it was previously installed without
```

I know the easiest solution is to uninstall my app and re-install again.
I want to make it easy for users. Is there a way to re-request the permission? Is there a broadcastreceiver to detect if Gmail app is being updated(installed) and request a permission again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Android (`PacakgeManagerService`) will only grant you permissions it knows about. It only knows about permissions from already installed apps. Everything else is ignored. Best you can do is check the installed Gmail version and instruct people to update it and then re-install your app. BTW, is this permission public? I don't think Gmail allows third party apps to reads its data any more, they changed this quite a while ago.

Comment: You are correct that the unofficial content provider, which was used in the past by several apps, is no longer available for external apps, but instead there is an OFFICIAL read-only content provider that you can use. It's more limited and does not grant you access to email contents but this is the one that uses the said permission. For more details on the Gmail API - read the following: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

Comment: A that one, it only shows labels and counts. Good to hear that it still works :)

Answer (score 0):

With this code in the onCreate of your Activity you can request every time the user starts the app which Gmail version is installed:

```
final int version_GB  = 236;
final int version_ICS = 405;

try 
{
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gm", 0);
    int version = Integer.parseInt(pInfo.versionName.replace(".", ""));

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && version >= version_ICS)
    {
        // Version 4.0.5 or higher on HONEYCOMB or higher
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO && version >= version_GB)
    {
        // Version 2.3.6 or higher on FROYO or higher
    }
} 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
{
    // not installed...
}
```

Be sure to allways check for newer Android versions first and then go to older versions.

Comment: thank you for the code to check the Gmail app version. However, what I "really" wanted to know is to re-request the permssion. Because even after the Gmail app is updated, my app still fails bc. it was installed without the permission.